# NextLink from Assignments doesn't seems to work

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

Im trying to retrieve Assignments for a User using:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/education/me/assignments
```

This works, and I get a paged result set back with an `@odata.nextLink`:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/education/me/assignments?$skiptoken=eyJGaWx0ZXIiOiJkdWVEYXRlVGltZSBsZSAyMDIwLTA0LTI0VDExOjI4OjUxLjg3NDk2MjZaIiwiT3JkZXJCeSI6ImR1ZURhdGVUaW1lIGRlc2MiLCJUb3AiOjUwMCwiTGFzdEVudGl0eUlkIjoiN2E1ZTM4NmEtZjg3NS00ZTFjLTgxYTQtYTVhZDhiMmE0MGJjIiwiTWF0Y2hpbmdMYXN0RWxlbWVudEZpbHRlckNvdW50IjoxfQ%3d%3d`
```

When actually performing this call I then get the following error:

```js
{
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "Query options must not be tampered",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-06-23T11:55:18",
      "request-id": "dd7e8dde-374b-4202-8289-6916521f000f"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if this a bug on the API or I'm missing a point here.

I've attempted to retrieve the Assignments via the Class endpoint as well:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/education/classes/dc962d8a-bd4e-4129-a626-0e3e9d129756/assignments?$skip=500
```

This yields the following error:

```cs
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException : Code: 19999
Message: Something failed, the API cannot share any more information at the time of the request.
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    date: 2020-06-23T10:32:04
    request-id: c519bddf-28c9-41e7-ab77-bd95cf0b7008
ClientRequestId: c519bddf-28c9-41e7-ab77-bd95cf0b7008
```

The calls are done via the Beta SDK for Graph found on Nuget but these calls fail via Graph Explorer as well. I have a requirement to get all assignments so I'm not sure what to do here.

Comment: This issue is also tracked here https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet/issues/114.